# What does the - option to env do?

Tags: env

From the man page for env:

```
The historic - option has been deprecated but is still supported in this implementation.
```

What does the "historic - option" do?

In particular, why does it change which version of python is run?

```
~:$ env python
Python 2.6.5 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (release26-maint, Mar 24 2010, 09:47:07)
```

but:

```
~:$ env - python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Historic"? That's a new one. Here's an excerpt from the GNU coreutils 7.6 `env(1)` man page:

> ```
>   -i, --ignore-environment
>           start with an empty environment
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ```
>   A mere - implies -i.  If no COMMAND, print the resulting environment.
> ```

Pass no command and see if there's a change in `$PATH`.

Comment: ah, so it seems a way to run something with no environment pre-set... i don't know off the top of my head how that will be handy, but i am going to find a use for it one day. +1

Comment: @cpbills: It's good for dealing with `$LD_*`.